# Increment of counter variable in SQL Transaction before commit

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I am using SQL Transaction and inside transaction I need to insert multiple record in one go.

But problem is that my Id is not identity. So, I need to get max id and insert it.
But when I get the max and increment +1. It is always same.

Following is the my code.

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE @maxId INT;
 SET @maxId = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM [dbo].[tempUser]);
    BEGIN TRAN
         BEGIN TRY  


         INSERT INTO [dbo].[tempUser] (id, principal, first_name, last_name, email, isActive) 
         SELECT @maxId+1, A.User_Id, A.FirstName,A.LastName, 'ab@gmail.com', 1 FROM ADUser_Table A 
         LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tempUser] B on A.User_Id =B.principal where B.principal Is NULL


    COMMIT TRAN
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH 
            ROLLBACK TRAN
        END CATCH  
END
```

How can I insert max id +1 with every record in sql transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of @maxid+1 you can add the @maxId with the row_number() as below.

```
SELECT @maxId+ (row_number()over(order by A.User_Id)) , A.User_Id,..
from [yourtable]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Row_Number` while inserting as next:-

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE @maxId INT;
 SET @maxId = (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM [dbo].[tempUser]);
    BEGIN TRAN
         BEGIN TRY  


         INSERT INTO [dbo].[tempUser] (id, principal, first_name, last_name, email, isActive) 
         SELECT row_number() over(order by A.User_Id) + @i , A.User_Id, A.FirstName,A.LastName, 'ab@gmail.com', 1 FROM ADUser_Table A 
         LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tempUser] B on A.User_Id =B.principal where B.principal Is NULL


    COMMIT TRAN
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH 
            ROLLBACK TRAN
        END CATCH  
END
```